# Unable to locate the element using id/name/xpath/CSSSelector

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to locate the username field with `id` element. But, getting *"unable to locate the element"*. Even I tried explicit wait/Thread/Xpath/CSSSelector, but still unable to locate the element.

Code:

```
naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("vinodchris");
//  WebDriverWait username = new WebDriverWait(naukriProfileCreation, 15);
//  WebElement id = username.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
//      By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")));
//  id.sendKeys("vinodchris");
```

Html:

```html
<div class="Xb9hP">
    <input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username"
        spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone"
        name="identifier" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId"
        dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">
    <div jsname="YRMmle" class="AxOyFc snByac" aria-hidden="true">Email or phone</div>
</div>
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`: Unable to locate element: `#identifierId`

Comment: Check if form located inside iframe

Comment: The element is hidden as hidden property is true.

Comment: Try with new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")));driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("vinodchris");

Comment: what is the type of variable naukriProfileCreation? is web driver type or web elemetn type?

Comment: @Andersson No it is out of iframe

Comment: @SnehaShinde tried both.but still unable to locate the element. Looks like element is hidden as Murthi said

Comment: @Vinoth , hidden element cannot be a reason for `NoSuchElementException` as it still can be located in DOM

Comment: use Thread.sleep() method before that element.

Comment: @Andersson yeah tried with Thread.sleep() as well.but no luck.  naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.id("login_Layer")).click();
  naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.linkText("Google")).click();
//  naukriProfileCreation.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("vinodchristopher77");

Comment: Here, when trying to login with google credential for naukri, it is moving to next window to login. how to find the element in next window and handle it

Comment: found the solution at last.   

for(String GoogleLoginWindow : naukriProfileCreation.getWindowHandles() ) 
  {
   naukriProfileCreation.switchTo().window(GoogleLoginWindow);
  }
naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("vinodchris");

Thank you all for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id('indentifierId')).sendKeys("vinodchris");
```

Comment: See why ['Try This: {code}' Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality) are not helpful to other readers and are prone to downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Before send keys try waiting for the control to be appeared. At second you can send keys:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("identifierId")));
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("vinodchris");
```